# Question tag: I like the color on me, don't you?

Tags: tag-questions

> Customer：I'll take this green sweater, **I like** the color on me, **don't you?**
>
> Shop assistant：I think it looks terrific on you.

From what I have been taught, I would say "I like the color on me, don't I?"
Why does the Customer change *I* to *you*? Is that correct? If so, what's the difference in meaning?

Comment: You're getting confused between ***tag questions*** (which are usually *rhetorical*, and either don't expect any answer at all, or strongly push for a "confirmatory" response), and "normal" questions. Thus *You do love me, **don't you**?, It's hot, **isn't it**?*, and *You're not the boss of me, **are you**?* are tag question. But in your example the "tag" form would be ***don't I?*** (which in this exact context would be a *very* colloquial / informal and perhaps aggressive usage). If you genuinely expect an answer it would be better to simply ask a natural question: ***What do you think?***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So **don't you?** in this situation is the abbreviation of a normal question(What do you think?) but not a tag question?

Comment: ...to expand on that "perhaps aggressive" point, ask yourself why you might add a tag question to a statement in the first place. In my examples, the "expected" answers (the answers the speaker assumes *would be given*, though he might not really care whether he gets a reply or not) are all "confirmatory" *(Yes, I love you. Yes, it's hot, No, I'm not your boss)*. In a way, the speaker is "challenging, daring" the other person to disagree (but he assumes he's right, so he doesn't really expect any disagreement). Your context simply isn't suitable for a tag question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've learned that a tag question could either imply a confirmation or a question depending on its intonation. If it's **don't I** with a up intonation, it would mean a question but not except a confirmation. Is it right or not?

Comment: To repeat my primary point - your context is *not suitable* for a tag question. The defining characteristic of a tag question is that *it "demands" a response **confirming the preceding assertion***. I assume your example customer wouldn't be "daring" the assistant to take issue with the fact that she (the customer) thinks the colour suits her, so ***don't I**?* is inappropriate. But ***don't you**?* isn't a tag question here, because it doesn't directly convert a preceding assertion (it asks what the *assistant* thinks, whereas the preceding assertion is about what the *speaker* thinks).

Comment: ...there are contexts where you could say something like *Well, I think Trump is an idiot. Don't you?*, but they rarely represent genuine requests for information. It's usually a "bullying" form, equivalent to *I think X, **and I dare you to tell me you don't agree** [if you're hard enough]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer is actually asking the shop assistant for *their* opinion, not just asking a rhetorical question.

In other words:

> I'll take this green sweater. I like the color on me. Do you like the color on me too?

Or:

> I'll take this green sweater. I like the color on me. What do you think?

In this case, asking somebody else *I like the color on me, don't I?* wouldn't make sense. It's not an obvious enough situation for the question to be rhetorical, and a questioner doesn't normally ask somebody *else* about the questioner's own feelings.

---

If it had been a rhetorical question, they would have stated something obvious and then asked a question only to emphasize the situation rather than to actually look for an answer.

For example, after eating three servings of a meal:

> It seems I was hungry, *doesn't it*?

Or to somebody who's finished watching a particular movie for the tenth time:

> You really like that movie, *don't you*?

Because the answer is self-evident, the questioner isn't actually expecting one.

Now, if the shopper came in every day for weeks and *always* bought a green sweater, then a rhetorical *I like the color on me, don't I?* could be appropriate. But there is no context for that in the simple sentence given.

Comment: I like your nicely-contrived final example! The best I could come up with was something along the lines of *Why do you drink so much? - I just like being drunk, don't I?*, which almost unavoidably conveys a note of aggressive dismissal. But yours is more likely just a whimsical lighthearted remark.

Comment: Your answer is great! What I'm confused is about this [video](https://youtu.be/zNUhMBmPbTU?t=2m36s) .

Comment: @preachers That video is correct, and it's true that such "negative" questions normally do repeat the subject. But it's not a rule that they have to. There isn't even a rule that you have to ask them in that form: (1) *We're going to the beach, aren't we?*; (2) *We should go to the beach, don't you think?*; (3) *Aren't we going to the beach?*; or (4) *Why aren't we going to the beach?* (Note: None of those questions are rhetorical; they expect an answer.)

Comment: @preachers: In English, ***real*** questions are uttered with a "rising intonation". That's to say, when ***don't you*** is louder and rising/higher pitched in a context such as *You like cake, don't you?* it's actually a ***real*** question - not a "rhetorical" tag question, as it would be if ***don't*** were less "emphatic". I think the explanation in your Youtube link is quite straightforward. Don't you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers My point about that video is that if I say "I like the color on me, don't I?" with a down intonation, it's a rude expression, but if I say it with an up intonation is it that it's a question and the questioner want to know the assistant's opinion? If it IS a question, is it interchangeable with "don't you?"?

Comment: We seem to be having difficulty communicating here. As Jason points out, *a questioner doesn't normally ask somebody else about the questioner's own feelings* - and I find it hard to believe that's peculiar to *Anglophones*. So as a "real" question (with rising intonation, ***not*** a "rhetorical tag question"), *I like the color on me, don't I?* barely makes sense. Why would a shopper ask a sales assistant what they themself (the shopper) think? Maybe you don't have to *repeat* the question in a tag, but you can't arbitrarily change it to a totally different question.

Comment: You've now given me a *serious* problem! I'm happy enough to have written ***themself*** (not ***themselves***) above, since it's a "singular they" usage. That's as per *Why would you ask him what you **yourself/yourselves** think?*, where the highlighted choice depends on whether you're addressing one or several people. But whether to use ***think*** or ***thinks*** for the verb has really got me scratching my head! I may end up having to ask for some more detailed analysis on ELU...

Comment: @FumbleFingers I forced myself to avoid pronouns when I wrote the awkward (but unambiguous) *a questioner doesn't normally ask somebody else about the questioner's own feelings*. It doesn't sound completely "right," but there was no way I could use a form of *they* without possible misinterpretation. I know it's *what they think*, even for a singular *they*. But both *they themself think* and *they themself thinks* sound right. Everything being equal, I would go with the plural verb form for consistency if nothing else.  At least neither are as awkward as my construction was . . .

Comment: I see your point. Personally, I'm pretty solidly behind *Why would a learner ask me what they [themself] think?*, because even though semantically ***they** = a learner = singular*, I can't ignore the *syntactic* side of things (whereby ***they*** is "always" plural). But including parenthetical *(**the shopper**)* in my example creates an equally strong demand for a singular verb form, leaving me stuck between a rock and a hard place when trying to figure out which "sounds best". Probably it's just an "unresolved" syntactic mess, a bit like *Where did you **use / used** to live?*